# Internally reroute request using NancyFx

Tags: c#, web, webserver, nancy

Is there any way in NancyFx from within a route handler to a) reroute to another route handler, b) reroute to an arbitrary URL (which happens to be OWIN middleware on the same server)?

Note, I do mean *reroute* and not *redirect* -- there should be no HTTP redirecting involved, only an internal rerouting of the request.